# check file exists on folder on server using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to check file exist on server using ajax. i have used below script
my server name is like **www.Mydomain.netp/Application_Folder/**

```
 var fileobj="../invoices/"+filename+".pdf";

  var pdfurl;
     $.ajax({
      url: fileobj, //or your url
    success: function(data){

     alert('exists');
   pdfurl = "http://Mydomain.orgi/Application_Folder/Invoices/" + Invoiceid + ".pdf";

         window.open(pdfurl, "PopupWindow", "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no");

     },
      error: function(data){



            alert('does not exists');

               pdfurl = "http://AnotherDomain.orgi/Invoices/" + Invoiceid + ".pdf";
                 window.open(pdfurl, "PopupWindow", "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no");
   },
 });
```

If file exists that time also i am getting into error part,
any other alternative ways to do this. above script perfect with localhost but not working on production environment

Comment: if the server is yours, a good solution is to create a rest api that gives you the right information.

Comment: log your `data` in console and check what you are getting??

Comment: i used var fileobj="~/invoices/"+filename+".pdf"; that time also no joy

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you provided seems to use calls from two different domains "Mydomain.orgi" and "AnotherDomain.orgi". You need to check if the another server you are requesting follows [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/). I will suggest console/debug your code And another minor thing that a variable named `Invoiceid` has been used. Please check if this also resolves well.

As long as the file existence is to be checked and as you have already included jquery on your page, I would just try the following

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

or if I follow the promise pattern I would go for the following:

```
var jqxhr = $.get( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
  });
```

For more [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)